# Extracting from formatted price the number for calculations in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, price

I'm working on a custom invoice template with the plugin [WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-pdf-invoices-packing-slips/) by Ewout Fernhout, and I faced with problem, when I want to create a more detailed product list on the invoice.

There is a foreach loop in the default template which shows all the products from the order:

```
$items = $this->get_order_items(); 

if( sizeof( $items ) > 0 ) : 

foreach( $items as $item_id => $item ) :
```

After that, I'd like to calculate the amount of discount in € and in % based on the `$items`. I dumped the content, and found that the product price is in `$item['price'] (string(119)`) and the original price is in the `$item['product']->price (string(3))`. I can echo the value of `$item['price']`, but when I want to get only the price from `$item['price']` (for example from 250.00€) with substring, but it is useless, returns with nothing or the length value of the function. (With the second variable - `$item['product']->price`, I don't have issues)…

```
$price = $item['price'];
echo $price.'<br/>';
echo strlen($price).'<br/>';
echo substr($price,0,10).'<br/>';
echo strlen(trim(substr($price,0,10))).'<br/>';
```

It displays:

> 250.00€
>   119
>   10

(It doesn't matter if I write 10 or 2 in the substring, the first occurrence of the substring will return with the length value). I've tried with reference but it neither works…

What can be the root cause?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

To get non formatted prices directly you can use:

1) For the Order line item you can get the WC_Order_Item_Product Object with:

```
$item_data     = $item['item']->get_data();
$quantity      = $item_data['quantity'];
$line_subtotal = $item_data['sub_total'];
$line_total    = $item_data['total'];
```

2) To get the related WC_Product object use:

```
$product_data = $item['product']->get_data();    
$product_price = $product_data['price'];
```

---

You can use simply [**`str_replace()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) removing **euro** symbol and **spaces** (**`'€'`** and **`' '`**) this way:

```
$price = str_replace( array(' ', '€'), array('', ''), floatval( $item['price'] ) );
```

> You will get a number (here **`250`**) that you can use in your calculations

Comment: Thank you for you answer!
Unfortunatelly it neither works. I forgot to mention I've tried str_replace. Here is the code, and the output:

$price = $item['price'];
echo "Original: ".$price;
$price = str_replace( array(' ', '€'), array('', ''), floatval( $item['price'] ) );
echo "New: ".$price.'<br/>';

--------------------------------------------

Original: 250.00€
New: 0

Comment: @HSzilard Just updated my answer … this should woork.